# limit with quaternion

Tags: limits, quaternions

Let $v\in \mathbb{H}$ and $q:t\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow q(t)\in \mathbb{H}$. That $q(t) \neq 0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $q^{-1}(t) = \frac{1}{q(t)}$. So don't confuse $q^{-1}(t)$ with inverse function(as pointed by rschwieb).

Than we have limit:

$$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-q(t+\Delta t) q^{-1}(t)}{\Delta t} =\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{q(t)-q(t+\Delta t)}{\Delta t} q^{-1}(t) = - q'(t)q^{-1}(t) $$

But I have trouble to find limit of this:

$$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{v-q(t+\Delta t) q^{-1}(t)vq(t) q^{-1}(t +\Delta t)}{\Delta t} = ?$$

Does it even exist? Can it be writen i terms of $v,q,q'$?

---

Context: I developed some system of recurrence equations. See And I want to find corresponding differential equations:

This is the system: $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$
\begin{align*} 
v_i(t_{n+1})& = p_i(t_{n+1})-p_0(t_{n+1}) = R_0(t_n,\Delta t) v_i(t_n) R_0^{-1}(t,\Delta t)\\ 
p_0(t_{n+1}) &= p_0(t_n) + \sum_{i=1}^n v_i(t_n) - R_i(t_n,\Delta t) v_i(t_n) R_i^*(t_n,\Delta t) \\ 
q_0(t_{n+1}) &= \{R_i(t_n,\Delta t)\}_i q_0(t_n)  \\ 
p_i(t_n) &= p_0(t_n) + R_0(t_0,t_n-t_0)v_i(t_0)R_0^{-1}(t_0,t_n-t_0)  \\
R_i(t,\Delta t) &= q_i(t+\Delta t) q^{-1}_i(t)\\
\{a_i\}_i &=\frac{\sum_{ \sigma \in \Pi_n } a_{\sigma(1)} \dots a_{\sigma(n)}}{||\sum_{ \sigma \in \Pi_n } a_{\sigma(1)} \dots a_{\sigma(n)}||}
\end{align*}

[here](http://tomsmathjourneys.blogspot.cz/) is how I came up with it

Comment: It looks like you might be using the notation $q^{-1}(t)$ to stand for the reciprocal of $q(t)$ rather than the inverse function? It would be good to warn readers about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be evaluated with an invocation of the product rule for quaternion functions:

$$(fg)'(t) = f'(t)g(t)+f(t)g'(t)$$

namely by considering $f(\tau) = -q(\tau)q^{-1}(t)$ and $g(\tau) = vq(t)q^{-1}(\tau)$, deriving at $\tau = t$. This means the result is $-q'(t)q^{-1}(t)v-vq(t)(q^{-1})'(t)$. Note that we have assumed $q^{-1}$ to be differentiable.

---

A derivation of the product rule goes along the standard lines, exploiting the identity:

$$f(t+\Delta t)g(t+\Delta t) - f(t)g(t) = f(t+\Delta t)\left(g(t+\Delta t)-g(t)\right)+\left(f(t+\Delta t)-f(t)\right)g(t)$$

Comment: @tom I had actually written a huge derivation which confused even myself (having this approach in mind) when I realised how much easier everything would become if I just derived the general rule. +1 to abstraction :).

Comment: @Lord_Farin Do you have a particularly nice resource for calculus in quaternions?

Comment: @rschwieb I'm afraid not, but perhaps the sources of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_analysis) are of some help to you?

Comment: @Lord_Farin I guess eventually I'll have to check those resources, but I was mainly checking to see if you had any favorites. Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure if you mean by quaternionic calculus theory of functions from reals to quaternions. but for function from quaternions to quaternions you can have a look at [this](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CD0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theworld.com%2F~sweetser%2Fquaternions%2Fps%2FQuaternionic-analysis-memo.pdf&ei=pPW1UYe6OoWO7Qb9o4H4Dg&usg=AFQjCNHtnWnZOagMgf8gZFrWqcrn4SMLHA&sig2=8FnCYPVC-dOnoI_sLhupjg&bvm=bv.47534661,d.ZGU)

Comment: Or you can try book [Geometric Algebra to Geometric Calculus](http://www.amazon.com/Clifford-Algebra-Geometric-Calculus-Mathematics/dp/9027725616) which builds analysis on top of Geometric(Clifford) algebra